# IIS http response header content expiration not displaying

Tags: http, iis, header

I am trying to set the http response header for content expiration. I would assume the response header from the server would display this, however I have been unable to figure out how this is transmitted back to the calling application.

When I set the "Web content expiration" to expire after 30 minutes, the response is still displaying the following.

```
Content-Length: 4691
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Fri, 16 Nov 2012 20:38:39 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
```

What I am expecting is something similar to the following:

```
Connection: close
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 689
Cache-Control: max-age=1800
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Thu, 08 Nov 2012 00:36:19 GMT
ETag: "f94ce92e467cc1:0"
Last-Modified: Wed, 31 Aug 2011 13:43:48 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
```

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25295740/content-expiration-is-not-working-as-expected.